# Split String into various Text elements

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a Searchbar on Top, the results get rendered into a fairly basic Listview. I want to have every word that's typed into the searchbar (not case sensitive) highlighted in the search result (string).

At the moment I do a basic split:

```
let split = question.title.split(this.state.searchInput);
```

and rendering it to:

```
<Text style={styles.title}>
 {split[0]}
</Text>
  {split.length > 1 ?
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text style={styles.fatTextResult}>
       {this.state.searchInput}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
       {split[1]}
      </Text>
     </View>
   :
     null
  }
```

This split obviously doesn't work when typing in 2 words that aren't connected in the search result. How can I accomplish that?

atm it looks like this..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
highlightWord( word , search ){

    var newWord = word.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");   

    if ( search.toLowerCase().indexOf(newWord.toLowerCase()) != -1 ){ // if word in question
        // highlight it
        return <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>{word}</Text>
    }
    else{
        return <Text>{word}</Text>
    }
}

renderRow( question ){

    let split = question.title.split(' '); //divide question in words
    textViews = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i<split.length ; i++){
        var word = split[i]; // get words
        textViews.push( highlightWord(word,this.state.searchInput) );
    }

    // return all words together (highlighted or not)
    return <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>{ textViews }</View>
}
```

**EDIT**

I added the first line on `highlightWord` to handle words with punctuation characters.

Comment: thanks this works, but not with words that end with a punctuation character... any ideas?